# Wake On Lan works w/ Magic Packet But Not w/ Network Activity

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, windows-8.1, wake-on-lan

My goal is to allow *any* network activity to wake up my Windows computer. My system currently wakes from sleep without any problem when it receives a Magic Packet but despite being configured to wake "On Network Activity" it does not.

In the device settings of my network adapter on the *Power Management* tab I unchecked **Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer**. For a couple of minutes after I put my computer to sleep I am able to wake it up by starting a Remote Desktop connection or triggering other network activity to my computer. I know Remote Desktop doesn't send a magic packet for WoL. I assume this works because the ARP table keeps my IP/MAC live.  When I no longer see the IP address with the `arp -a` command, wake on network activity no longer works.  Just to reiterate, magic packets ALWAYS works.

What do you guys think is my issue? Would I need a router that would allow me to statically map my computer's IP address to its MAC address? I have a managed switch, would it help to configure that mapping on it?

I have run the `arp -s` and `netsh forcearpndwolpattern=enabled` commands.

All device drivers are updated and the BIOS is on the latest version. I confirmed device management settings in the OS are correct.  Is the problem still my NIC or router?

Some background:

- Latest hardware drivers installed for Realtek PCIe GBE Ethernet adapter (this is wired)
- Windows 8.1 Professional (also attempted on Windows 7 Ultimate)
- Router: Apple Airport Extreme (6th Gen 2013)

Comment: ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?